# Android service crash if activity is finished before service is completetd

Tags: android

In my application i start an service from a activity using startService command. This service is used for uploading file so it will take time.
So what i want is my Activity should be finished and srvice should keep on doing its work. For this purpose after calling startService() i call the activity finish also.
Because of this my service stops in between abruptly while if i dont call finish of activity everytihng works fine. I want to know how to make it possible so that service keep doing its work while Activity (who started this service) is finished.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: How about you show us some code or the stacktrace of the exception so we can identify what's wrong?

Comment: Post code and logcat

Answer (score 0):

You should do your uploads via IntentService because:
•The Service runs in background but it runs on the Main Thread of the application. 
•The IntentService runs on a separate worker thread. so it runs your codes even when your application's Activity isn't open

Use something like this:

```
package com.example.test;

public class MyService extends IntentService{

public DownloadService(){
    super("DownloadService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0){     
    // Here is your codes
}
```

and [here](http://javatechig.com/android/creating-a-background-service-in-android) is a good sample ;-)